# Как изменить режим набора кода в Android Studio

Tags: android, android-studio

Ребята, хелп!

Уже незнаю, что делать. В Android Studio поле очередного обновления сам включился режим замены символов при вводе кода, отключается на insert, но стоит кликнуть в коде в другое место или переключить вкладку она снова включает этот режим. Как отключить этот режим раз и навсегда и забыть как страшный сон?

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Перейдите в меню настроек: `File > Settings > Editor > General > Appearance` и там отключите пункт меню `Use block caret`:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Если же не получится решить проблему таким способом, то можно попробовать сбросить настройки AS. Для этого перейдите в папку `[SYSDRIVE]:\Users\[your username]` и удалите папку `.AndroidStudio`

Answer (score 1):

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]В верхнем меню "Tools" снять галочку с пункта "Vim Emulator"